# Skin loading issues for rich:extendedDataTable richfaces 4.5.17

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am having problems with loading the richfaces 4.5.17 skin for extendedDatatable.eccs while rendering the table. the Richfaces skins works perfectly fine for all other panels and datatable.

I am migrating richfaces project from 3.3 to 4.5.17 and I see no errors in logs as well. F12 debug tools just showing panel.eccs

The div tag and table tag are loading the css headers perfectly fine.

My web.xml settings:

```
org.richfaces.skin
blueSky
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you share example code? Is there an error message?

Comment: there is no error message or exception in the logs. just cannot load the skin for rich:extendedDataTable but I see the page is loading all the rf-edt css styling but just not able render in the browser.

Comment: this is what i have figured out richfaces 4.5.17. Because I am using a custom skin, i am assuming there is some problem with css reference. after I managed to get packed.css then I was able to get the default styling to rich:extendedDataTable, but still I need to get the custom styling using  packed.css.

Comment: If you're were using a custom skin in RF 3 you probably need to update it.